# c++ linked list creation linked list of linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

the code send error in this line 
    course["CS"].student=new Course*[1];

i want create linked list of courses contain linked list of students

here is the code

```
struct Student{
    string name; 
    int id; 
    int grade; 

    Student(string n, int i, int gd ){

    name=n; 
    id=i;
    grade=gd; 
    }
};

struct Course{
    string C_Name; 
    Student **student;
    int index;
    void add_student(Student *new_student){
    student[++index]=new_student;   

    } 
};
Course course[4];
void init(){

    course["CS"].student=new Course*[1];
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: `"CS"` is not a valid index for an array. Use std::map/std::unordered_map if you want to index with strings

Comment: also, `student` is a `Student` pointer, so assigning a `Course *` won't work.

Comment: If the user is talking about creating linked lists I would assume std::map is not permitted although the question should be updated to mention the requirements.

Comment: If you want a linked list of courses, then you probably shouldn't create an array of them. Same thing for the students.

Comment: [Error] invalid types 'Course [4][const char [3]]' for array subscript

here is the error @Shaggy

Comment: and what should to do @interjay

Comment: You shouldn't use arrays at all. What you probably should do is study linked lists a bit more before you even start writing any code. And it looks like you need to review the chapter on arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't contain any kind of linked list, but only plain arrays.
Apart from that, the last line (`course["CS"].student=new Course*[1];`) contains some invalid syntax.

- An integral or enum type must be used to access an array (`string`s or `char[]` wont work)
- Assigning a `Course**` to a `Student**` object is not allowed

A linked list contains of nodes each having a pointer to the next node. The last node usually has a pointer with value `nullptr` (C++11) or `0` (older standard). Note: There is also a so-called double linked list, where every node also stores a pointer to the previous one.
A node contains all the data, that you want it to store.
Example:

```
struct Node {
    Node* next;
    // other node data here
};
```

To create a linked list, you first start with one node and set `next = nullptr; // 0`. To add another node just create a new one and change the pointer of the first one.
Example:

```
Node* node1 = new Node();
node1 -> next = nullptr;

Node* node2 = new Node();
node2 -> next = nullptr;

node1 -> next = node2;
```

You start to see a pattern. To insert at the front just create a new `Node` and set its `next` to the first already existing node. To insert between two nodes, say `node1` and `node2`:

```
node1 -> next = newNode;
newNode -> next = node2;
```

To make it nice one usually writes a wrapper class containing functions such as

```
InsertNodeAt(Node* node, uint index);
Node* GetNodeAt(uint index);
RemoveNodeAt(uint index);
```

Since you have two different types of objects (`Student` and `Curse`), you might want to use templates and avoid writing a linked list class for each type.

If you want to create your linked list yourself, I recommend doing some additional research (google is your friend) as I have only mentioned a few things.

If you don't mind using the c++ standard library you might be interested in using the already pre-made linked list classes `std::forward_list` (standard linked list) and `std::list` (double linked list).

Comment: i will work on it that's easy way, but keep in contact i will need you plz

Comment: Well I'm not going to write your code for you. I think you would learn it much better if you'd do it yourself. :)

Comment: Anyway if you just want code you can use for your project, google it. A lot of people have already done example implementations.

Comment: Miss understand i say if i face obstacles i will ask you not more :)

Comment: Feel free to ask then. :)

Answer (score 0):

in c++ you didn't defined course["string"], so you may not use "CS" as an index to a Course type object
and *.student is a class **Student's** object, not **Course** type

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
 using namespace std;

struct Student{
    string name; 
    int id; 
    int grade; 

    Student(string n, int i, int gd ){

    name=n; 
    id=i;
    grade=gd; 
    }
};

struct Course{
    string C_Name; 
    Student **student;
    int index;
    void add_student(Student *new_student){
    student[++index]=new_student;   

    } 
};
Course course[4];

void init(){
    // Need allocate space for a new object of class "Course"
    Course course;
    course.student = new Student*[1];// "student" is Student type but not Course 
}

int main()
{
    try{
        init();
    }
    catch(...){
        return -1;
    }
    std::cerr <<"your debug info" <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And in my own opinion, in c++ you may try reference and it's counter in class Course's definition to class Student. Using printer in this way may cause error unexpected.

Comment: could you show me what  insert function  gonna to be ?

Comment: you can get the format of an insert function in c++ or OOP books. Just google it.